# Android Studio 4.0.1 : Build Failed : option 'android.databinding.enableV2' is deprecated

Tags: build.gradle, android-databinding, android-build, android-studio-4.0

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 4.0.1 and my build keeps failing with the message:

**The option 'android.databinding.enableV2' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
Databinding v1 is removed.**

I tried adding:

```
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding = false
android.databinding.enableV2=false
```

to  gradle.properties and gradle-wrapper.properties. but neither solved the issue. Is there something that has to be added or removed from build.gradle possibly?

Answer (score 9):

Remove these lines from `gradle.properties`:

```
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=false
android.databinding.enableV2=false
```

And rather fix the reason why you've added them properly ("could not make a guess" ...). Also see if not another module might use option `android.databinding.enableV2` and try to manually delete the build cache and build directories once. Updating the IDE will only update the Gradle plugin version, it certainly changes nothing else. If you should have such concerns, you probably should use some kind of version control system, which shows all changes in a `diff` (this also provides unlimited undo and lots of other useful features); Android Studio supports that without plugins.

Answer (score -2):

The issue was that the line:

android.databinding.enableV2=false

had to be removed from the gradle-properties file in my **HOME** directory . On a MAC it is located here:

~/.gradle

Comment: Why you've unaccepted my answer just to post the same? This is a project-level Android DSL specific setting, not a global setting. If you previously added it into there, you've added it into the wrong place, therefore this answer is rather misleading than leading. The question also doesn't indicate OSX and in this case, I'd doubt the difference claimed.

Comment: You did not suggest the HOME directory and that is where the problem lied. I up-voted your answer because while it did not solve my problem it led me to the correct answer.

Comment: This settings was never meant to be in there, even if it might be picked up from there (because it makes no sense to apply such Android-specific settings to all Gradle projects - or even all Android projects). Such configuration can lead to issues one can't explain (in other projects), because it just will apply the settings.