Gradle error : The option 'android.databinding.enableV2' is deprecated
I'm trying to build my android project, but I've got this error :
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
The option 'android.databinding.enableV2' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
Databinding v1 is removed.

I am using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
and distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-bin.zip

refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910213/android-studio-4-0-1-build-failed-option-android-databinding-enablev2-is-d

Thanks for the link, but I tried the solution and it didn’t work—any other suggestions?
